# How to split a single word separated by space form single column into two columns

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am having the following records in column A

```
Column A

4.0K 0000000.png
4.0K 0004.png
32K 00(1).gif
16K 001.gif
```

**My need is to split the size and name of the image in two different columns.** That is

```
Column A    Column B

4.0K        0000000.png
4.0K        0004.png
32K         00(1).gif
16K         001.gif
```

How can I do this using Openoffice Calc.Version is 2.3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Beginning with OOo 2.4, you could use the "**text to columns**" functionality to achieve this. There's a [nice tutorial with screenshots](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/text-columns-calc-convert-openoffice.html) how to apply it. If upgrading isn't a viable option for you, there are some other methods described (mainly using the csv import options).

EDIT: The blog post i've linked to points to [some macros for splitting text on multiple columns](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/26/how-to-convert-text-to-columns-in-openofficeorg-calc/). This would be an option for OOo 2.3 and prior.

Comment: "*How can I do this using Openoffice Calc.Version is 2.3?*" So, there's no Date > Text in Columns yet. Thus, i mentioned that feature beginning with 2.4...